# NetworkManager recognizing only a specific configuration file

Tags: wifi, configuration, raspberry-pi, raspbian, networkmanager

I'm trying to connect to the 'eduroam' wireless network at my university through a Raspberry Pi using the command line.

After struggling with wpa_supplicant configuration files I decided to use NetworkManager since an already working configuration was ready on another Linux host. After connecting through Ethernet and SSH to the Pi I used `scp` and transferred directly the already compiled configuration file from the Linux host machine.

After making sure the same connection to the wireless network was also working on the Pi, I deleted the original configuration file and used a custom script to generate the file changing only the credentials for the wifi authentication.

This time NetworkManager didn't recognize any connection (the same as an empty `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` folder). So, thinking that the error could come from my script I created another file from scratch on the Pi (with `nano`) and just copied\pasted the content of the original file on the Linux host. Still, NetworkManager wasn't recognizing any connection.

As a final test, I decided to use `scp` again, transfer the original file, strip away the old authentication details and then append the new ones. In this way it works, even if the file content is identical in the two situations. Thinking about a permission kind of problem I used `chmod --reference=(original_file) (new_file)` but nothing changed. Basically, it only seems to work with the same exact file of the Linux host machine or some direct modification of that file.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't find a solution but I did figure out a workaround. Here is what I did:

1. Format SD card
2. Copy NOOBS files onto SD card
3. Boot into NOOBS recovery
4. LOGIN WITH YOUR EDUROAM CREDENTIALS FROM THE NOOBS SCREEN
5. Install raspbian

I can access internet through the eduroam network on raspbian.